# Dynamic actions in lightning record page not showing Send Email quick action

Tags: dynamic, lightning-record-page

I created a new action to send an email in Buttons,Links and Actions of a custom object.I also created a new lightning record page for that object and enabled dynamic actions.But I couldnt find the new action that I created for Email in the dynamic actions of the lightning record page.How to get it in lightning record page?

Action:
[image]

Email action that I created not appearing in dynamic actions in lightning record page:
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include code and (probably more importantly) metadata snippets for your action.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Send Email quick action doesn't show up in the highlights panel where all buttons are located. Send Email quick actions are added either under Activity tab or Feed tab. That is why its not visible under dynamic actions as dynamic action feature is applicable for the buttons which are being displayed in hightlights panel.

[image]